# Notification is opening Gallery in the React native background handler

Tags: android, ios, react-native, notifications, intentfilter

```
const options = {
    taskName: 'Example',
    taskTitle: 'ExampleTask title',
    taskDesc: 'ExampleTask description',
    taskIcon: {
        name: 'ic_launcher',
        type: 'mipmap',
    },
    color: '#ff00ff',
    parameters: {
        delay: 1000,
    },
    taskProgressBarOptions:{
        max: 100,
        value: 80,
    }
};
```

As i am using react-native-background-actions and as I am clicking on the notification and it is opening Gallery by default but i want to my app. Let me know if there is anything for this.

I am not able to get how to use this intent filter to open my app on click on the notification instead of Gallery

```
<intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">
                      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                      <data android:scheme="yourSchemeHere" />
                  </intent-filter>
```

Please check and update it.

This is the Android Problem and IOS this module is not working. Is this problem due to real device or something else.